# should trees in an ensemble be trained on samples of the same size?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, sample-size, boosting, ensemble-learning

I know that if `bootstrap=True`, then "for each tree, N samples are drawn randomly with replacement from the training set and the tree is built on this new version of the training data. This introduces randomness in the training procedure since trees will each be trained on slightly different training sets. In expectation, drawing N samples with replacement from a dataset of size N will select ~2/3 unique samples from the original set".

But why can't we train trees for choices of different sizes, with different class balances?

I'm trying to understand if there are any methodological limitations to train estimators on different samples, both diffeternt in terms of class ratio and size